# Data transfer between Ubuntu/Windows to network

Tags: windows, ubuntu, transfer, large-data

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 as dual boot. If I am working on Windows, in order to transfer Ubuntu files to windows, I know that I can use DiskInternal Linux Reader. Also, if I am logged in Ubuntu and if I want Windows data from another machine, I can use secure shell or putty to mount the Windows volume and then transfer data to other machine on network. Suppose, on the other way, if I logged in Windows and I want Ubuntu files from another Ubuntu/Windows machine on network, how do I transfer data? If it is a small data I can transfer to windows via Linux reader and transfer via ssh. But my data is too large, so I don't want this idea.

Comment: There is some application which i used for this called winscp. Not sure if it will satisfy your requirement but take a look at it . https://winscp.net/eng/download.php